# How to get all images from a bunch of subdirectories with React/Electron/Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm building an app with electron forge. One of the things I'm building at the moment requires me to include about 140 images in a directory with the following structure:

```
- assets
  - cards
    - ai
      - ai.jpg
      - ai.mp3
    - ar
      - ar.jpg
      - ar.mp3
```

... and so on

I want to be able to just build an object that looks like this:

```
{
  ai: {
   path/to/ai.jpg,
   path/to/ai.mp3,
  },
  ar: {
   path/to/ar.jpg,
   path/to/ar.mp3,
  }
}
```

I tried using require-directory but to no avail - that only seems to return my .js files:

cards/index.js:

```
var requireDirectory = require('require-directory');
module.exports = requireDirectory(module);
```

Cards.js:

```
import allCards from '../assets/cards';
console.log("::::::", allCards);
```

(I know, using require and import - bad, was just testing this out though)

I'm not sure how or if it's even achievable. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but here is a routine I cobbled together from various SO answers. Given a directory, if recursively (and synchronously) walks through all subfolders and pushes the paths to image files into an array and returns it.

I'm no Javascript hero so there are probably better ways – such as using [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) or [walkSync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk-sync)

This uses [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath)

```
var flattened = [];
flattened = walkSync(dir, flattened)
```

---

```
var walkSync = function (dir, filelist) {

    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    filelist = filelist || [];
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if (fs.statSync(upath.toUnix(upath.join(dir, file))).isDirectory()) {
            filelist = walkSync(upath.toUnix(upath.join(dir, file)), filelist);
        }
        else {
            var ext = upath.extname(file).toLowerCase();
            if (ext == '.jpg' || ext == '.jpeg' || ext == '.png') {
                filelist.push(upath.toUnix(upath.join(dir, file)));
            }
        }
    });
    return filelist;
};
```